# how to get store information by locale code

Tags: magento-1.9, localisation

How can get store id by locale code right now I have

```
$locale='en_US';
```

reverse of this code

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('general/locale/code', $storeId);
```

now based on this I want to get **store id** I could not find possible way. any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code will do the trick for you.

```
 $locale='en_US';
 $allStores = Mage::app()->getStores();
 foreach ($allStores as $_eachStoreId):

     if($locale==Mage::getStoreConfig('general/locale/code',$_eachStoreId->getStoreId())):
       $storeId=$_eachStoreId->getStoreId();
       break;
     endif;
  endforeach;
  echo $storeId;
```

Answer (score 2):

There can be same local for multiple store thats why there is no alternative of this.

```
$locale='en_US';
$defaultStores = Mage::app()->getStores();
foreach ($defaultStores as $_store)
{
    if($locale==Mage::getStoreConfig('general/locale/code',$_store->getStoreId()))
    {
        $storeIds[]=$_store->getStoreId(); 
        // you can use break here if want first value only
    }
}
  echo '<pre>';print_r($storeIds);die;
```

Comment: This is same answer to @fmeExtensions

Comment: @QaisarSatti, Yes but he is consider only 1 store for 1 locale. But it may possible multiple store on a same locale. So technically his answer is wrong.

Comment: after testing both answers worked for me. but i need single store id. thanks for answer.